# How to perform validation when updating a unique field using Http\Request in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I have a `customers` table that I use a `CustomerRequest` to validate the fields, through the use of the `rules` function. The table has an `email` field which is required and is unique. This works fine when I create the customer, however when I update the customer info (let's say I got their last name spelled wrong) my request fails because the `email` address is already in the database.

Here is my CustomerRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'givenname' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:customers,email',
    ];
}
```

I would like to reuse the `CustomerRequest` for all of the customer vaildation, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check here for request type as well as customer id for update and then return rules according to request. Something like this

```
public function rules(Request $customer_request)
{
return [
    'givenname' => 'required',
    'surname' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|unique:customers,email,'.$customer_request->get('customer_id'),
];
}
```

Comment: Just curious to know: what if there is no `customer_id` being passed as a request ? What should be the solution then ?

Comment: If no customer_id then this request must be for new insert, if found then it must for update. Here laravel will handle existence of customer_id.